# Planes, trains and Automobiles

Tags: rebus, emoji

Another c-19 riddle for the petrol heads out there :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community Wiki (please add to this with the below format if you have an answer):

**Format:**

Clue No (@Name):

> Answer (Brief explanation)

---

1 (@Stiv):

> Toyota (toy+otter)

2 (@JMP):

> Chrysler (cry-sleigh)

3 (@Deolus):

> Lockheed blackbird

4 (@JMP):

> Orient Express

5 (@JMP):

> Rolls-Royce (rolls-roy(al)-sea->ce)

6 (@Stiv):

> (Dodge) Viper (say what you see...)

7 (@JMP):

> Flying Scotsman

8 (@Stiv):

> Lamborghini (lamb+O+ghee+knee)

9 (@Ak19):

> Bullet (train)

10 (@Randal'Thor):

> Ferrari (fair + r + i(eye))

11 (@JMP):

> Citroën

12 (@Stiv):

> Spitfire (spit+fire)

13 (@JMP):

> TGV (tea-ghee-v) [French high-speed train]

14 (@Stiv):

> [Tristar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_L-1011_TriStar) (three stars)

15 (@Stiv):

> Suzuki ("Sue"+zoo+key)

16 (@jafe):

> [Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_(automobile))?

17 (@JMP):

> Airbus

18 (@Stiv):

> Renault (rain+O)

19 (@Randal'Thor):

> Eurostar (the train from UK to mainland Europe)

20 (@JMP):

> Concorde (can-cord)

Comment: all good thus far !!

Comment: 9 May be   [Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinkansen) train or Royal Enfield [Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Enfield)

Comment: 16 [Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mowag_Eagle)

Comment: 3 [Lucky Eagle](https://www.myshiptracking.com/vessels/lucky-eagle-mmsi-244690591-imo-0) ? Lock + He + Eagle

Comment: This answer is not a community wiki as intended. @Omar may edit and check the box labeled "community wiki" to correct this.

Comment: Bullet train 

Comment: 16 and 3 incorrect

Comment: 3 [lockheed blackbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird) lock-head-blackbird?

Comment: 3. I had lockheed raptor (bird of prey) in mind but blackbird fits ! Thanks

Comment: I think we're done here. Thanks all !! Will mark as answered when system lets me (2 days).